# How to configure sqlite3's tcltests?

Tags: sqlite, tcl, tk-toolkit, recipe

For research purposes, I am trying to run the `sqlite3` full test suite.

I am running under Linux for this test.

I believe I have installed the correct libraries

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev
```

And when I run the `configure` command, it finds `tcl`

```
checking whether to use an in-ram database for temporary tables... no
checking if executables have the .exe suffix... unknown
checking for Tcl configuration... found /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh
checking for existence of /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh... loading
checking for library containing readline... no
checking for library containing tgetent... no
checking for readline in -lreadline... no
checking readline.h usability... no
```

Then when I run `make test` it ends with:

```
Time: orderby8.test 5080 ms
Time: orderby9.test 291 ms
Makefile:1201: recipe for target 'tcltest' failed
make: *** [tcltest] Killed
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell because your question misses important details:

- What *nix exactly?
- More importantly, which Tcl versions are installed by `apt`?
- How do you obtain the `sqlite3` sources incl. test harnesses?

I just tested fine the following:

- Ubuntu Xenial
- `apt-get install tcl tcl-dev` (turns out to be 8.6.7)
- `wget https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-src-3250200.zip`
- `unzip sqlite-src-3250200.zip`
- `cd sqlite-src-3250200`
- `./configure && make test`

... and it succeeds to complete the `make test` run:

```
...
Time: orderby7.test 6 ms
Time: orderby8.test 115 ms
Time: orderby9.test 6 ms
Time: oserror.test 49 ms
...
Time: zipfile2.test 10 ms
SQLite 2018-09-25 19:08:10    fb90e7189ae6d62e77ba3a308ca5d683f90bbe633cf681865365b8e92792d1c7
0 errors out of 147094 tests on builda Linux 64-bit little-endian
All memory allocations freed - no leaks
Maximum memory usage: 9278848 bytes
Current memory usage: 0 bytes
Number of malloc()  : -1 calls
```

It seems that `oserror.test` crashes whatever Tcl in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much, that gives me a direction to go in.  In my case I was running on Raspberian (long story, don't ask.)    I'll install Xenial in a VM and see what happens.  I'll also update my question with the missing details when I can.